# how to display images saved in a folder after uploading it

Tags: php, html, image-gallery

i simply want that after i upload an image it will be redirected to a page that displays all the images. The images are saved in a folder. i have found some examples but they are so complicated, i just want to try the simple way first.

this is the HTML code for uploading image:

```
<form action="upload_image.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
Title:<input type="text" name="title" id="title" />
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

this is the PHP code to save the other details in the database:

```
include('../IFM-mobile_website/include/connect.php');
$title=$_POST['title'];
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
)
{
 if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"]) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
    {
    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    }
   else
    {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
    "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    echo "Stored in: " . "../IFM-mobile_website/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
    }
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Invalid file";
    }
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your file uploaded path and the path in which you are showing image are different

uploading to : `"upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]`

showing it from : `"../IFM-mobile_website/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]`

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "../IFM-mobile_website/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

To show all the images in a folder :

```
$a = glob('Your/path/*.{jpg,gif,png}',GLOB_BRACE);
print_r($a);
```

Comment: how will i able to display the images from the folder to another page. the code i have above for uploading is working fine.

Comment: You need to give the relative path, based on from were you are calling the image, in your above case if the uploading works fine then change the line after that to this : `echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];` removed `../IFM-mobile_website/`

Comment: i really appreciate your help, but what i am trying to achieve is to get ALL the IMAGES from the folder and display it. I assume that i will be using a loop here, but i cant figure out how to do that. Can u please help me? i want to get out from this dilemma asap. :(

Comment: @anastasia : Use `$a = glob('Your/path/*.{jpg,gif,png}',GLOB_BRACE);` to get all the images in a folder